# JavaScript anchor tag parser from editor

Tags: javascript, css, html

I am making an editor using JavaScript and I am looking for a way so that when user types .. as input in editor div, 
The link shows up in other window and disappears from editor div as I clicked a button 
Something like activelink.js live demo, but dunno how to implement it.

Edit::   Users can enter links in the text editor by using tags. For example, “This is a link ”. When the user clicks “Done”, the editor should detect if the user has entered a link tag in the editor. If so, add that text as an actual link (like this: This is a link) to the bottom of the page (outside of the text editor). The links at the bottom of the page should be colored red and blue alternatively, and they do not need to actually link to another site.

Comment: I don't understand cleary what you want? Explain more or add example or demo.

Comment: Users can enter links in the text editor by using tags. For example, “<a>This is a link </a>”. When the user clicks “Done”, the editor should detect if the user has entered a link tag in the editor. If so, add that text as an actual link (like this: This is a link) to the bottom of the page (outside of the text editor). The links at the bottom of the page should be colored red and blue alternatively, and they do not need to actually link to another site.

Comment: I add my answer. Is it your solution?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/qfrwr0bf/8/   .. i am making this .. now check it its not working in this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this example

```js
$("button").click(function(){
    var text = $("textarea").val();
    var anchor = text.match(/(<a.*?\/a>)/g);

    if (anchor != null){
        anchor.forEach(function(value, index){
            $("#anchorBox").append(value);
        });
    }
    $("textarea").val("");
});
```

```css
#anchorBox > a {
    display: block;
}

#anchorBox  > a:nth-child(odd) {
    color:red;
}

#anchorBox  > a:nth-child(even) {
    color:blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea></textarea>
<button>done</button>
<div id="anchorBox"></div>
```

Comment: Yea it can work , there is one more problem, the textare are multiple paragraphs <p> with same class name, and this function to work for all paragraphs in editor div and apeend that to append div.. So will that work?..and how about alternative color?

Comment: What is meaning of `textare are multiple paragraphs <p> with same class name`? Where is `paragraphs <p>` in textarea?!

Comment: I mean that in editor div, when enter is pressed It make a new para, (<p><p\>) , sorry about textarea, if three lines are written with 2 enter then there will be 3 paras. Thats what I meant

Comment: There is no problem, it work fine. You can test it and see result. Write other tag in textarea. Write in textarea`<p>` tag and in it `<a>` tag and see result.

Comment: there is no text area in my project,only div contenteditable and when enter pressed a para is enter ,this is should work for those para(multiple paras),

Comment: sorsorry for saying about textarea

Comment: Test in my example. Write you html in textarea of example and see result.

Comment: yea this works for textarea.. but the input clears after button press

Comment: It shouldn't do this work? After inserting link to page, textarea content must clear.

Comment: how about take the case of paragraph(2 para tags with contenteditable),then how the code change?

Comment: Do you want to change code? What do you do with changing code?

Comment: your code is correct. but it only for 1 text area.i want to create it for multiple paragraphs so that it will work the same.could you help me out?

Comment: $("button").click(function(){
    var arr = [];
    $('textarea').each(function () {
        arr.push(this.value);
    });
    for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
 {
 anchor = arr[i].match(/(<a.*?\/a>)/g);
 if (anchor != null){
        anchor.forEach(function(value, index){
            $("#anchorBox").append(value);
        });
    }
 }

    
    $("textarea").val("");
});

Comment: <textarea name="hello"></textarea>
<textarea name="hello"></textarea>
<button>done</button>

Comment: do this work the same?

Comment: No, it isn't. It select content of multiple textarea. I select `<a>` tag using regex. If you want to select other tag or multiple tag in your textarea, you need to change regex. See https://jsfiddle.net/a9nm7ss7/. Write in this example `<a>` and `<p>`

Comment: No.i want to select a tag only but not from textarea but from paragraph

Comment: i mean if write <a>text to display</a>, it will display that text as link but that thing will be written it paragraph

Comment: See https://jsfiddle.net/a9nm7ss7/1/

Comment: @chitrank https://jsfiddle.net/qfrwr0bf/4/

Comment: Nice!! But could it be generalize for n textareas? As it will be headache to define ID to each text area..

Comment: See https://jsfiddle.net/qfrwr0bf/5/ for unlimited textarea!

Comment: see this pls... https://jsfiddle.net/qfrwr0bf/6/

Comment: Use `text()` instead `html()` in line 4. `html()` make character encoded and this isn't what we want.

Comment: jsfiddle.net/qfrwr0bf/8  watch it pls ... its not working here

Comment: @chitrank First child of `#container` stayed on `button` and you can't click on button! Change position of it.

Comment: Change button position?

Comment: @chitrank Move it to top.

Comment: But there is nav at top

Comment: So do I put button above nav?

Comment: Do I put button above nav tag (bootstrap)

Comment: @chitrank Move it little to top. For example `30px`.

Comment: I was thinking can I reorder paragraphs by drag and drop?